# how to fix this code of embeded youtube with different thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to put different thumbnail for my youtube video, but when I do this the video open above the image and its not work at all... here is my code 
Note: I dont needed to be autoplay

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'VIDEO ID',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            $('#play_vid').click(function() {
                event.target.playVideo();
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#player').hide();
            $('#play_vid').click(function() {
                $('#player').show();
                $('#play_vid').hide();
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="player"></div>
    <img id="play_vid" src="IMAGE ID" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: I try this and the image and video are separate on page